# Tetration uniqueness by $ A = \inf \sum_n a_n^2 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, tetration

Let $x > -2$ and $f(0) = 1,f(x+1) = \exp(f(x))$

And $f$ is a taylor series :

$$f(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$$

where the $a_n$ are all real and all nonzero and $f$ has radius $2$.

(Notice $f(-1) = 0, f(-2) = \ln(0)$. The functional equation holds for all $x>-2$.
So the radius is at most $2$.)

(There are infinitely many solutions now but we talk about adding a condition below..)

Let $A$ be a real number ; the infimum of the sum of $a_n^2$. It is thus a condition on the reals $a_n$.

see :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

$$ A = \inf \sum_n a_n^2 $$

Do we have uniqueness of $f$ here ?
In other words is there a unique $f$ that minimizes $\sum_n a_n^2 $ ?

Bonus question :
If we add the condition $f ‘(x) > 0 $ for all $ x >0$ to the above , do we get uniqueness for $f$ then ?

I thought about calculus of variations, but my understanding is limited.

Comment: I don't understand the $A = \inf \sum_n a_n^2$ part. Is this a condition on the $a_n$? What is $A$?

Comment: @Karl $A$ is a real number ; the infimum of the sum of $a_n^2$. It is a condition on the reals $a_n$ yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: But what set of numbers are you taking the infimum of? A sum is not a set.

Comment: @Karl the lowest value of that sum

Comment: Oh, so the infimum is taken over all possible choices of $f$ meeting the other requirements? In other words, you're asking if there is a unique $f$ that minimizes $\sum_n a_n^2$?

Comment: @Karl yes that is it.

Comment: Is everything clear for everyone ?

Comment: Any ideas ? Anyone ?

Comment: Maybe some more context/motivation would help. Some approaches to extending tetration to real heights are covered [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Real_heights). Are you proposing the power series coefficient condition as an alternative to one of the conditions used there?

Comment: @Karl yes I am not telling people how to construct a solution. Im talking about all analytic solutions and these conditions.

Comment: last hour for the bounty !!

Comment: It seems to be nontrivial !